# Can someone make me understand how did they use geometric distibution in this

Tags: probability, statistics

[image]

[image]

I want to under stand part two of the question

I have added the answer

Can anyone make me understand how did it equals geometric distribution and how did they calculate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) gives us the probability distribution of the number $N$ of Bernoulli trials needed to get one success.

In your example, "success" is defined as $\text{observation}>5$.

The pdf of the geometric distribution is given by
$$P(N=k)=p(1-p)^{k-1}$$

and the cumulative probability function is

$$P(N\leq k)=1-(1-p)^k$$

Now the complementary cumulative distribution is given by
$$P(N>k)=1-P(X\leq k)=(1-p)^k$$

In your case you want to estimate the probability of $N$ being bigger than the expected value of $N$, namely $E(N)$.

Since we know that the random variable $N$ is distributed geometrically with parameter $p$ , then $E(N)=\frac 1 p$.

And the answer to your question then becomes 
$$P(N>k)=(1-p)^{1/p}$$

Now just replace $p$ by the corresponding value.